# How to update all client records from CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription

My app stores locally all the records that `CloudKit` stores. So it is not the big data small phone concept, but all data server - all data client concept. I need all the updates from time to time when app launches again.

Should I set up for all existing record type `CKSubscription`?

- It might come to much notification from server, even though I guess there is a 'silent mode', there should be a limit on storagecapacity of iCloud notification collection.

Should I delete all local record when app launches and download again from `CloudKit` to get the updates?

- Need to update too much data every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudKit has the `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` for this. You can request all changes within a zone since the previous update. You can then synchronize that data with the storage inside your app.

If you do use subscriptions, then if there are multiple notifications send in a short period, there is a big chancre that your app won't get all notifications. Apple will limit that. This is why after processing received subscription notifications you should also execute a `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation` after you received a notification.

Comment: so you recommend for frequently changing record types only use `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` without remote notification?

Comment: yes, ckFetchRecordChangesOperation will work without CKSubscription. You will even get all data from all recordTypes that are changed. Choosing this over subscriptions is a functional decision. You could use both if you have a recordType with important data that requires to be up to date. Then do remember that you will also receive the same changes with the CKFetchRecordChangesOperation

Comment: You also have to be aware that the CKFetchRecordChangesOperation will give you all data within a zone. So if the client does not need all the data, then this is probably not right for you.

Comment: `CKFetchRecordChangesOperation` is deprecated as of iOS 10 :(